# Get value with column names in cassandra

Tags: php, cassandra

Hi I am using php with cassandra database. I am trying to get username and password from cassandra database. It return the below result.

```
Cassandra\Rows Object(
[columns:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => Cassandra\ColumnSpec Object
            (
                [keyspace:protected] => team1_groupboxx
                [tablename:protected] => gb_adminusers
                [name:protected] => au_username
                [type:protected] => Cassandra\TypeSpec Object
                    (
                        [type:protected] => 13
                        [customTypename:protected] => 
                        [keyType:protected] => 
                        [valueType:protected] => 
                    )

            )

        [1] => Cassandra\ColumnSpec Object
            (
                [keyspace:protected] => team1_groupboxx
                [tablename:protected] => gb_adminusers
                [name:protected] => au_password
                [type:protected] => Cassandra\TypeSpec Object
                    (
                        [type:protected] => 13
                        [customTypename:protected] => 
                        [keyType:protected] => 
                        [valueType:protected] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[rowCount:protected] => 1
[columnCount:protected] => 2
[current:protected] => 0
[rows:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => k2badmin
                [1] => f2c452187d4af19966187e15f1e944e1
            )

    )
```

)

But I want to get the query result in below format.

```
Array (
       [au_username] => admin
       [au_password] => f2c452187d4af19966187e15f1e944er              

  )
```

where au_username and au_password are the column names of my table.

Comment: What query you are fireing also show ur key constraints

Comment: I fired the following query ."SELECT au_username, au_password FROM gb_adminusers WHERE au_username='username' AND au_password='password' ALLOW FILTERING"; I had created index for both two columns (au_username,au_password ).